# Unable to load canvas into THREE.Texture();

Tags: javascript, html

I am unable to load my image onto the side of a cube I am making.
Currently, the image loads onto the canvas, but I can't seem to add into the texture.

```
function createPictureCanvas(text, font, foreground, background, xres, yres, backOpacity) {
    var canvas = createHiDPICanvas(xres, yres);
    // var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    image = new Image(),
    imageUrl = "images/placeholder.jpg";

    image.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        alert("hi");
    };
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    image.src = imageUrl;
    var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
    texture.anisotropy = renderer.capabilities.getMaxAnisotropy();
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture, transparent: true });
    return material;
}
```

Comment: Try removing `img.style.display = "none";` maybe?

Comment: Added that as i wanted to just load the image onto a canvas and not display the img on the img tag.
Removed but it still has the same issue. 
Unable to find any error message with it thou.

Comment: Do you see if your image is correctly loaded in the network panel (devtools)?

Comment: Is the function `onload` is called when your image is set to the `src` property?

Comment: Yeap, if I put an alert inside that method, it alerts. It just does not draw the image.

Comment: Are you sure your image is not displayed in the canvas? What it the image size? Does you canvas works if you manually modify it?

Comment: As of right now when i load the function, it turns out empty screen, my image is 2500 x 1666. Not sure how to manually do it as it returns to form one side of a cube i am making, Unable to find it in dev tools.

Comment: Seems like if i add in 

document.body.appendChild(canvas);    
The function will display a canvas, but i still can't get it to load onto the cube.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `width` and `height` and clearing your context. This is the code i use:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    image = new Image(),
    imageUrl = "images/placeholder.jpg",
    width = 100,
    height = 100;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

image.onload = function() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
};
image.src = imageUrl;
```

Comment: are you supposed to type it as canvas ..., new line context , or is it supposed to be ;

Comment: @kai I just inlined the declaration of each variables (you can type `var i, j, k;`). Is it what you are asking?

Comment: @kai all variable are not the same type

Comment: Currently, have this warning when trying to run the code 
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://threejs.org/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Comment: Tried the method but still having the same result, could it be because of the above warning?

Comment: @kai I do not think this warning is related to your issue as it is about cookies.